# Water softener - preplumb includes drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, water-softener

I'm planning to install a water softener but there is no drain, just the water pipe loop to cut into and connect up with.  The plans for the house say "water softener preplumb for" - does that mean there should be a drain somewhere for it to empty into or does that only imply the water pipe?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a loop of pipe somewhere near where water enters home usually, it is installed to make water softner hookups easier. If you search "construction water softener loop" and hit images you should see something like in those pics. Also it is rare to find they installed a drain usually just the water loop at least here In Texas.

Comment: Yeah it has a loop - why would they not install the drain if the drain is necessary?  Wouldn't that be part of a "preplumb"?

Comment: Depends on location I guess but here is Texas they just drill a hole for the drain usually.  Is the another mechanical item close that has a drain? They may expect you to plumb to it if close.  But YES TO YOUR QUESTION yes they plumbed the water and not anything else, and that just from experience.

Answer (score 1):

Read the instructions for the water softner you bought or intend to buy to see their recommendations for the drain hook-up. I live in western Pa. and for my drain the installer ran the tubing overhead to the laundry tubs. You rarely need a drain at the softner since for most units the drain can be run overhead to a remote drain. If you run the drain line to a sewer drain make sure that you include an "air gap fitting" to make sure that in the event of a sewer back-up water can not enter the drain and contaminate your water supply.